# AWS HTTP API Gateway Getting Double Messages from Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway setup to pass values from HTTP calls to a lambda.

When I use postman, everything works great. When I use the browser, however, I get 2 calls. One of which is the same as the postman call, the other is missing all of the arguments and causes an error.

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "retry_api" {
  name          = "${var.environment}_${var.cdp_domain}_retry_api"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  description   = "To pass commands into the retry lambda."
  target = module.retry-support.etl_lambda_arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_retry_api" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIgatewayInvokation"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = module.retry-support.etl_lambda_arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.retry_api.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

I'm giving the parameter as such:

```
?type_of_retry=retry_event
```

And on the first event it comes in correctly:

```
'rawQueryString': 'type_of_retry=retry_event'
'queryStringParameters': {'type_of_retry': 'retry_event'}
```

On the second event the rawQueryString is an empty list and there is no queryStringParameters key at all.

If anyone knows how to eliminate that 2nd event from being generated that would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that 2nd message was a favicon request.